# write bash script that branches depending on output

Tags: bash

what i need to do:

1. Run "Art list --pool=prototype | grep tg" in the command line (Sample of output command: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y19A4.png)
2. Find first line from output whose 3rd column is "AutoTestd@atest" or "", and has no words after character ']' (e.g. line starting with tg106 in example)
3. If present, run "Art grab --pool=prototype tg106" (using first 5 characters of the line found)
4. If not present, wait 5 secs and go back to 1.

This is what I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello World!"
grabbed=false
while !grabbed do
   for /f "tokens=1,5,9" %%i in ('Art list --pool=prototype | grep tg') do
      if ("%%j" == "AutoTestd@atest" || "%%j" == "<free>") then
         echo "found"
         # grab a DUT
         Art grab --pool=prototype %%i
         grabbed=true;
      else
         echo "trying again..."
      fi
   done
   sleep 5
done
```

However, i get these errors when trying to run it:

~ @bs340.sjc> ./my_script

Hello World!

./my_script: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `"tokens=1,5,9"'

./my_script: line 6: `   for /f "tokens=1,5,9" %%i in ('Art list --pool=prototype | grep tg') do'

Comment: Do you have some attempted code to show us?

Comment: This question is tagged `bash` but your script's syntax looks like `cmd` / Windows batch script. Which is it?

Comment: i am actually trying to write it for Mac OS, running tmux and mosh on iterm2

Comment: the answer by "that other guy" doesnt capture line with tg106 (refer to image link above) and keeps running.

Comment: `for /f` is Windows batch syntax, not bash syntax.

Comment: "Write a program that does this specialized thing I want" is pretty much the very definition of "too localized" with respect to StackOverflow's rules for asking good questions.

Comment: okay, what i mainly needed was the syntax for parsing multiline bash command output. i tried searching for a solution here but couldn't find any. should i rephrase my question or should i post another question?

Answer (score 2):

```
# Until we find a line containg word1 or word2, and ending with a ]
until line=$(command1 | grep -E '(word1|word2).*]$' | head -n 1); [[ $line ]]
do
    # Sleep and try again
    sleep 5
done

#Run the final command with the first 5 chars from that line
command2 "${line:0:5}"
```

Comment: If you don't want to use character positions, you have to figure out how to identify the part of the line you want to use. For example, if you want the first word up to a space, use `command2 "${line%% *}"`

Comment: thanks, there was actually a space after ] my bad, i've change it and now it gets the line. if we allow for spaces before the first word, how do i get it?